# Trying to create a tabbed, popup, rising, footer

Tags: html, css, menu, tabs, footer

I'm wanting to create a similar menu effect to the footer at [crackerbarrel.com](http://crackerbarrel.com/), where the tabs at the bottom roll up when you hover over them. It keeps the tab on the top and the whole thing slides up, with room for additional content.

I found a similar effect at [CSSplay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/css3-rising-tabs.html). I guess my main question is, what is this effect called, so I can find tutorials?

I've been searching "rising," "pull-up," "drop-down variants," and have found a lot of cool CSS tricks today, but not anything about this effect specifically.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery SlideUp. Here: [Jquery SlideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Example:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slideup_slidedown

The examples you gave can be made with a `hover` handler registered to the target element.

[jquery .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

A more complete demo, from scratch:

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/